# Hibernate unnecessarily update joined tables

Tags: java, hibernate, join, sql-update

Basically, I have 2 classes P & M, and their corresponding tables T_P & T_M, and they are joined in a one-to-many relation, one P has a set of Ms. Something like this:

```
<class name="P" table="T_P">
    <set name="ms" cascade="all" lazy="false" inverse="true">
        <key column="P_ID" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_M_P"/>
        <one-to-many class="M"/>
    </set>
</class>
<class name="M" table="T_M">
    <many-to-one name="p" column="P_ID" foreign-key="FK_M_P" class="P"
                 update="false" not-null="true" cascade="none"/>
</class>
```

Now when I make changes to P and ask Hibernate to update DB. It's very likely Hibernate will do a batch of updates, one to T_P, several to T_M, and I know the later part is not necessary as I didn't change those Ms. But I think because my object is detached, hibernate has to update everything.

So my question is, in my case, can I ask Hibernate to only update partially, and not to make excessive DB hits? Or other suggestion to optimize this is also appreciated. But this is a legacy program, and I may not be able to make drastic changes.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as `inverser="true"` mapping is concern, it will only work for bidirectional association.**
in your configuration , you have not mentioned mapping for P in M.

```
<class name="P" table="T_P">
<set name="ms" cascade="all" lazy="false" inverse="true">
    <key column="P_ID" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_M_P"/>
    <one-to-many class="M"/>
</set>
</class>
<class name="M" table="T_M">
     /*mention mapping for P here, if you want to use inverse property properly*/
</class>
```

issue might be because of `cascade="all"` mapping.
try to set `cascade="save-update"` in mapping for collection.

you go through the following [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) , which contain simple/basic example of parent-child relationship.

sample mapping for parent-child relation is as follow.

```
/*parent contain set of child entity*/
<set name="children" inverse="true">
<key column="parent_id"/>
<one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>


/*child has reference of parent*/
<many-to-one name="parent" column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
```

I hope this help you to resolve issue.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I forgot to mention child's reference of parent.